# How to not to pass argument if empty?

Tags: ruby

I upgraded ruby to 1.9.3 from 1.8.x Not sure if pony gem was upgraded during that process too but the point is that I was using this code to send out an emails

```
Pony.mail(
    :to => to, 
    :from => from,
    :subject => subject, 
    :body => Nokogiri::HTML(body_with_footer).text, 
    :html_body =>  body_with_footer, #.gsub("\n","<BR>"),
    :attachments => attachment_to_send,
    :via => :smtp, 
    :via_options => {
            :address     => $smtp,
            :port     => $smtp_port,
            :enable_starttls_auto => false
    }
)
```

attachment_to_send should be a hash of files to be attached. When the hash was empty no attachment was send. Now I got a pony error complaining about the hash being "".

So I introduced a if condition `attachment_to_send==""` so I call pony with or without the attachment part.

Is there any way to manage that? So I have only one code where I call pony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handled with ternary operator `attachment_to_send.empty? ? nil : attachment_to_send`

```
      details = {
            :to => to, 
            :from => from,
            :subject => subject, 
            :body => Nokogiri::HTML(body_with_footer).text, 
            :html_body =>  body_with_footer, #.gsub("\n","<BR>"),
            :attachments => attachment_to_send.empty? ? nil : attachment_to_send ,
            :via => :smtp, 
            :via_options => {
                    :address     => $smtp,
                    :port     => $smtp_port,
                    :enable_starttls_auto => false
            }


Pony.mail(details)
```

Answer (score 1):

prepare your attachment array by checking empty condition following way,

```
 tmp_hash = {:to => to, 
             :from => from,
             :subject => subject, 
             :body => Nokogiri::HTML(body_with_footer).text, 
             :html_body =>  body_with_footer, #.gsub("\n","<BR>"),
             :via => :smtp, 
             :via_options => {
                            :address     => $smtp,
                            :port     => $smtp_port,
                            :enable_starttls_auto => false
                             }
             }
```

and

```
tmp_hash[:attachments] => attachment_to_send
tmp_hash[:attachments] => nil if attachment_to_send.empty?
```

or 
directly,

```
 tmp_hash[:attachments] =>  attachment_to_send if not attachment_to_send.empty?
```

and then

```
Pony.mail( tmp_hash)
```

should work